# Extending classes?

Tags: php, oop

Ok so I have two files, one called Database.php and another called Auth.php...

```
class Database {
  // method inside
}
```

Then I have Auth:

```
class Auth extends Database {
  //methods inside
}
```

They are both in the same directory. I know my object list will get pretty huge and I rather not put 5 million includes at the top of every class script.

How do I make it so the extends keyword automatically searches all the classes in the same directory?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand how inheritance works

Comment: `I rather not put 5 million includes at the top of every class script` - tell Java developers about it :D

Comment: You should avoid extending every class that are not related! Think about using interfaces instead. Otherwise code quickly becomes a nightmare to maintain since it is so strongly coupled.

Comment: Also you might want to start using namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP autoloader feature - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php.

This is example of autoloader in Nette framework - http://doc.nette.org/en/auto-loading

Comment: Thank you =) This is what I needed. I knew about the autoload, I just didn't know how to use it. Just one simple function. I didn't know it.. well autoloaded xD I thought it had to be called or something which ruined the whole point of my thinking process.